# socket io green text by accident

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

when I stop the text from scrolling  and click the green text option it makes the whole last line green, after it was typed, which I don't want.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var list = [];
var started = true;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('message', function(msg){

var patt = /(.{1,})\1{2,}/;
var isFalse = patt.test(msg);

if(!started || msg.length > 144 || msg.length == 0 || isFalse || msg === " " 
|| msg === "  ")return;
if(!list.includes(msg))list.push(msg);
else return;
io.emit('message', msg);
});
socket.on('getColor', function(isGreen){
      io.emit('getColor', isGreen);
});

});
```